# Cannot change region of Apple ID without credit card details

Tags: apple-id, iphone

I have an iPhone 6s Plus. I want to change the country and region but I'm being asked to enter my credit card details, with no other option.

What should I do? Is there an option without entering credit details and changing the store to US?

Comment: Could it be a security reason?

Answer (score 1):

This [Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203905) explains that a valid payment method is always required when changing regions.

> When you change the country or region of an existing Apple ID, you must provide a payment method and update your billing options. If you want to remove your payment method after you change the country or region, you can change your payment information to None.

You may be able to set up a new Apple ID for a different region [without entering credit card information](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204034), but any apps purchased (whether free or not) with that Apple ID would require that Apple ID be signed in to get updates.

To create a new account without a payment method, go to the App Store, iBooks Store or iTunes Store on your device. Tap Get on any free item and follow the steps for setting up a new account. When prompted for a payment method, None should be on the list. If it's not, you must enter a payment method.

Comment: The page you link to no longer has that text anywhere in it

Comment: @theonlygusti The "[Change your Apple ID country or region](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389)" Apple support webpage has similar wording to that above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change a region with by buying an iTunes prepaid card from the region you intend to change to

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to contact apple support in your country.  I requested a call online and they phoned me back within the minute and sorted it out immediately. Fantastic service and free!

Answer (score -2):

I believe its not possible to change to region B once you have set up a credit card in region A unless you have a credit card that is valid in B (or at least thats how I think it works) however i'd expect that apple support can probably change your region for you.

As a small side note, if you don't have a credit card associated with your account you can change region as much as you want (unless you have unused balance)

**TL;DR:**

I don't think its possible, ask apple support.

Edit #1:
Decided to quickly google this. Here is a link that probably does a better job at explaining than me. [Support.apple.com](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201389)

Comment: It would be nice to know why I'm being down voted. If you want people to answer correctly (or whatever I'm doing wrong, idk what) then it would help to say what is being done wrong and how it could be fixed.

Comment: You're likely getting downvoted because you cannot simply change regions at will, whether you have a credit card associated with your account or not. Changing regions requires a payment method be entered with a billing address that matches the new region. The only time "none" is available as a payment method is when you are first setting up a brand new Apple ID via the App Store (even setting it up via other methods requires a credit card be added the first time the App Store is accessed).

Comment: @tubedogg ive been able to change regions at will multiple times while having none as a payment option. Most recently I switched to get Pokemon Go early, for example. So I'm still not sure why thats worth down voting, especially since nobody else seemed to want to answer (until you answered, that is). But whatever, you did a better job answering anyways, in my opinion, so I'll leave it there.

Comment: From a quick reading of the question and answers, my guess as to why it's being voted down is because it just took a quick google search to find the support article you linked to.  That article answered your question.  I didn't downvote, I'm just speculating for future reference.